# Can' get html with remote login and Curl

Tags: php, curl, dom, field, remote-access

I'm trying to grab a page of a website, protected by a login/password (I have an account with credentials!). All other websites I rech it successefuly, but on this one it doesn't work! :-(

Here is the form on the page :

```
<form id="login-form" action="https://www.boutique-technipond.fr/connexion" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="back" value="">
          <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" value="" required="">
            <input class="form-control js-child-focus js-visible-password" name="password" type="password" value="" pattern=".{5,}" required="">
          <button id="submit-login" class="btn btn-primary" data-link-action="sign-in" type="submit">
            Connexion
          </button>
  </form>
```

And here is the php code I use (url = https://www.boutique-technipond.fr/connexion and data = "email=xxx@xxx.com&password=xxxxxxxx" :

```
function article_techp($url, $ref_url, $data, $login, $proxy, $proxystatus){
    if($login == 'true') {
        $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        fclose($fp);
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    if ($proxystatus == 'true') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$ref_url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    ob_start();
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($ch);


return $html;
}
```

The return page is the one which is displayed when not connected... So credentials are not working... The credentials are ok, if I use them to connect in the browser, it works!
Any idea please?

Comment: Is the website serving native html, or do they use something like javascript to produce dynamic content once you have signed in, perhaps to prevent people from scraping their site? Don't they have an API you can use?

Comment: Yes, this is native, the CMS used is Prestashop...

Comment: When doing something like this, you probably want to submit all form fields. I'm seeing at least two hidden ones, including `submitLogin`